# How does HDFS modify data

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

If HDFS is does not allow modification of files, how come HBase store and modify data? Its difficult to search for an answer to this question because results are mostly oriented to HBase physical data format. But I could not find how does HBase get around the problem of immutability of HHDFS files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HBase stores data in HDFS in an indexed form. Oversimplifying things, the HDFS files have the keys stored in sorted order so that looking up a particular key is fast. HBase data storage is taken care of in the RegionServers (RS).

In the RS, the keys are first written to an in-memory store (called memstore). The memstore stores the new keys/updates an deletes. After a certain threshold, these keys are pushed to HDFS as a new index file. Updates are taken care of by timestamps - the assumption is that the latest version is the only valid version. So if the previous index file has the same key, it will be ignored. Deletes are the same as updates, the only difference is that deletes have a special type field which have a flag marking the key as deleted.

I have made some simplifications:

- The index file format has changed a lot over time. Initially, it was the [`MapFile`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/MapFile.html). The more recent versions of HBase use a format called `HFile` which has metadata and optimizations specific for HBase.
- The writes are recorded on disk on a WAL (Write-ahead log) before they go into the memstore. This is for prevention of data loss.

I also found a couple of excellent related articles, which you should read:

- http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-io-hfile-input-output/
- http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-write-path/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really helpful and also thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

HBase does a few things (the following is a simplification but it explains the general idea):
for consistency it writes to WAL files the data as it arrives - so no changes to data  there.

The "problem" is with the HFiles where the data is stored in an ordered manner. The first thing HBase does to solve this is that it holds the data in memory (memstore per region) and only flushes them to disk when they get filled. This saves some of the re-writes.

Waiting before saving only solves some of the problem there are still cases where you need to rearrange data - (e.g. repeated updates to the same key etc.) so the second thing HBase does is compactions where it reads multiple HFiles and creates new ones with the merged data (and deletes the old files)